Session is not being saved when I am using Codesandbox.io
I am bulding a simple educational example of login form that stores information on session, using ExpressJS and express-session package.
Everything works well when I am running the application on localhost.
However, when I am running the application on codesandbox.io, the user authenticated information it is not stored neither cannot be recovered.
app.js
const session = require("express-session");
// Set up session middleware
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "your_secret_key", // Change this to a strong, unique secret key
    resave: true, // Do not force save session if it hasn't been modified
    saveUninitialized: true, // Save new sessions that are not initialized
    name: "express-tutorial",
    cookie: {
      secure: true, // Set to true only if using HTTPS
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60, // 1 hour session expiration
    },
  })
);


index.js
/* GET home page. */
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  console.log("session-luiz");
  console.log(req.session);
  if (req.session.user) {
    // User is authenticated
    res.render("index", {
      title: "Express Tutorial",
      user: req.session.user,
    });
  } else {
    // Redirect to login if not authenticated
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
});

// Hardcoded credentials for demonstration
const USERNAME = "luiz";
const PASSWORD = "teste123";

/* GET login page. */
router.get("/login", function (req, res, next) {
  res.render("login", { title: "Login", error: null, user: false });
});

/* POST login page. */
router.post("/login", function (req, res, next) {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  // Check credentials
  if (username === USERNAME && password === PASSWORD) {
    // Store user info in session
    req.session.user = { username };

    // Save session and then redirect, ensuring only one response is sent
    req.session.save((err) => {
      if (err) {
        // Send error response if session save fails
        console.log(err);
        return next(err); // Use next(err) for proper error handling without sending another response directly
      }
      res.redirect("/"); // Redirect after session is successfully saved
    });
  } else {
    // Render login page with error message if credentials are incorrect
    res.render("login", {
      title: "Login",
      error: "Invalid username or password",
      user: null,
    });
  }
});

/* GET logout page. */
router.get("/logout", function (req, res, next) {
  req.session.destroy((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send("Failed to log out.");
    }
    res.redirect("/login");
  });
});

I am trying to store information on session and recover this information on other requests.

This happens because two reasons:
Codesandbox builtin preview open the application inside an iframe embedded in another domain when you are using the built-in Preview panel of Codesandbox.
Codesandbox open the application inside a virtual proxy
To solve (1), you need to open the application on a separate tab:
Click on the button to open the Preview in a new tab/window and the problem will be solved.

This problem happens because the built-in preview panel Codesandbox uses an iframe inside the main codesandbox.io domain.
Opening the preview on a separate tab, the application is opened directly in the specific app domain, such as https://zd5ns7-3000.csb.app/
As cookies are domain-isolated, you must open the application on a separate tab using the correct domain.
To solve (2), you must include the following line:
app.set("trust proxy", 1); // Trust first proxy

